# Running Tomcat and IIS server in parallel

Tags: database, iis, tomcat, redirect

I have my application running on Tomcat server successfully. I want to run some aspx files for which i need to link up with other server like IIS. How to send a query string to the IIS server and get back the result say in an HTML file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and its quite simple. I created a Iframe and passed the other server url through the tomcat and it worked.